# My WIFI device is sometimes identified as Qualcomm and some time as PowerColor

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, lenovo, atheros

I bought a new LENOVO ideapad 310 and installed Ubuntu 16 on it.

About half of the times that I start my machine (or reboot) my WIFI works and the other half it doesn't.

I noticed that lspci outputs differently when the WIFI works and when it doesn't. This below is the result of the diff:

```
~$ diff lspci_when_wifi_works.txt lspci_when_wifi_broken.txt 
15c15
< 02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 30)
---
> 02:00.0 Class 8280: Tul Corporation / PowerColor Device 0040 (rev 20)
```

I don't know if the Qualcomm identification is correct, but when the WIFI is identified as Qualcomm everything works and when it is identified as PowerColor it doesn't.

Any ideas how to make it work always? On every boot?
Any more information/logs/command-output that I can supply to help?

Thank you,
Sela.

```
~$ uname -a
Linux sela-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK 4.4.0-45-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 14:12:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ii  linux-firmware                                1.157.4                                       all          Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
```

Comment: Qualcomm is correct. What is the kernel version? `uname -a` output.

Comment: This looks like a kernel bug. Report it to Launchpad by running `ubuntu-bug linux`. Follow the directions and describe the problem there when prompted.

Comment: PowerColor is your graphics card. Could be the assignment is changed due to lag during boot. Maybe a bootchart for both situations might reveal if that is the case

Comment: I think the wireless adapter disappears anyway.

Comment: Are you sure the adapter is not there? You may need to update firmware.

Comment: @Pilot6 you think the problem might be Lenovo's firmware? Is that what you're suggesting I should update?

Comment: If you are sure that you do not see the Qualcomm device in `lspci`, then it is a bug in the combination of Lenovo BIOS and the Linux kernel. If you can upgrade Lenovo BIOS, it may be resolved. Otherwise report it as a kernel bug to find a workaround.